# Installation of Valgrind changes permission to usr/local/include/

Tags: macos, gcc, valgrind

I attempted to install valgrind on Mac OS X 10.8.

After completing install any attempt at running gcc gives the following error.

error: /usr/local/include/stdio.h

Of course I could change the permissions on usr/local/include but I'm curious if others have faced this and what the did to correct?

Thanks

Comment: Is that the full error it gives?  Because that's just a filename, not an error.  You say the permissions were changed but don't show any evidence of that - what did they change from/to?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I used time machine to restore the directory /usr/local/ and then reinstalled the "command line tools" from apple's developer site.

Comment: It is not the complete error.  I left out the part just before "error" where it prints the line number in my source file that it attributes to the error.  Thanks for your help.  I used os x time machine to restore the directory /usr/local/ and then reinstalled the "command line tools" from apple's developer site.  Now everything is working normally as far as I can tell.  However, I do not have valgrind.  I really don't know much about where valgrind installs to but it appeared to be entirely in /usr/local/.

Comment: I believe that normally all the library .h files are kept in usr/include/ but perhaps when valgrind installs it has its own?  Or moves them to its own private directory?  In any case the directory /usr/local/include while marked writable/viewable/executable still could not be opened and had a nice little red "do not enter icon" on the folder.

Comment: My initial question is perhaps mistated.  I did not know previously that usr/local/include/ wasn't the standard location for the library .h files so I believe that the location that contained stio.h which had previously been working was now tampered with.  Of course I would like to install valgrind but don't want the weird after effects.  Thanks again.

Comment: Did you install valgrind via homebrew? And why is there a stdio.h in /usr/local/include, instead of /usr/include? That seems unusual, for OS X.

Comment: I didn't install Homebrew.  Is that necessary before installing valgrind on osx?  It is a mystery to me why gcc was looking for stdio.h in usr/local/include instead of /usr/include.  I believe this was only the case post-installation of valgrind.

Comment: I have now installed valgrind via Homebrew.  Running gcc now down't freakout.  However running valgrind produces a slew of errors which I know are not present (I was testing a simple hello world program).  Not sure if it is really that buggy on osx but it doesn't appear to work at all.